# How to disable Apple Watch auto sleep in an app?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch

I have a written an app for Apple Watch and I don't want the watch to go to sleep while my app is running. How can I disable the idle timer on watch?

Comment: It's ridiculous that my watch always go to sleep while using Xcode debugging, and I have to enter the password everytime.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The limited framework disallows this.